# Slowing down DC motor with generators

Tags: current, dc-motor

I am building an ebike and I have an idea to slow down the bike using its own momentum. Just wondering if this is a good idea or would even work from an electrical perspective.

The bike is configured that the main drive motor is directly linked to the chain with moves the wheels. Therefore, inertia of the motor affects the inertia of the entire bike and vice versa. When I slow down the momentum of the wheels spins the now unpowered drive motor. Since the drive motor is permanent magnet, it will generate a current of its own. In normal coasting, I plan to recharge the battery with this. But in braking condition, I want the motor to spin down fast without extensively using the mechanical brakes.

So I have a small power drill motor I am thinking to attach to the brake caliper such that as the brake lever is pressed, the motor shaft comes into contact with the spinning bike rim before the brake pads do (press harder and actual mechanical braking is applied). The motor spins up and generates current, can I route this current back to the main drive motor but in reverse polarity to get the drive motor to slow down? The drive motor powers the bike by spinning clockwise, would the motor slow down by applying the braking motor's current in the polarity so it would want to spin counter clockwise?

How would the current generated by the unpowered drive motor itself effect this dynamic? Would the braking generator have to produce a voltage higher than what the drive motor is generating to get the magnetic fields to reverse and oppose the inertial rotation? Also will this process generate a lot of heat?

If this wouldn't work I'd love to know of more efficient methods of electronically braking a DC motor. I can just use the braking generators to activate a brake light:)

Comment: For many motors, the simplest way to electrically brake the motor is to just connect the leads together. (Don't try that at home unless you know what you're doing! There are a few hazards you'd have to consider before just attaching a switch in parallel with a motor.)

Comment: What kind of motor did you pick, if any?

Comment: @Mas Both drive and braking motor are brushed permanent magnet DC. I know these motors aren't the best for the application but I'm tryna use what I have

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you’ve described is called *regenerative braking*. The motor is run as a generator, converting kinetic energy into power that is pumped back into the battery.

It’s the norm in hybrid and electric cars, but almost unheard-of on e-bikes.

Why? Regeneration requires a more complex motor controller than a non-regenerative type, and it doesn’t work with a center-drive with free-wheel (it can work with a hub drive though.) As it is, the e-bike cognoscenti don’t seem to think it’s worth it, as the extension of range possible with regen is relatively minor on an e-bike.

Comment: I made it so the pedals freewheel but the motor is still connected to the drivetrain. Can this not be done with simple wires? I thought the voltages would just naturally average out without a controller modulating stuff lol. But yea if its too complex then I will keep regen for just coasting

Comment: With a brush motor the drive polarity can simply be reversed. With a BLDC the coil drives need to add the braking path. In more formal terms, a regen-capable controller is ‘two quadrant’ while a simple speed control is ‘one quadrant’. Controllers that support forward and reverse are also ‘two quadrant’, but not the same quadrants as forward and brake.